# built a wordpress website, but google console giving me javascript log

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-search-console

i've built my own WordPress website and think I've done a "good" job, but certainly not that technical to fix issues,

although i did fix 6/7 errors i had, and chuffed with that.

but i have something coming up on google search console,

```
Array(0) []
https://example.co.uk/about-us/:46
```

this appears on every page i have,

my question -

is this actually a issue? or am i trying to find a fix for something that isn't a issue?

i can't find anything on page inspection, so it just seems to come up on google search console, any suggestions will be welcomed.

n/a, not advanced enough XD

Comment: what's at line 46 in your page source? `view-source:https://example.co.uk/about-us/`

Comment: It looks like it's just being logged, not an actual error. An error would state what the error is.

Comment: Open a page (eg this SO page), press F12 to get browser tools, select `console` tab and copy+paste this into that area: `console.log("log");console.error("error")`  - this will show you the difference between how a "log" is shown vs how an "error" is shown.

Comment: It could be from a component you've used on [tag:wordpress].   Try a blank page (ie without any of your custom html / scripts) and see if the message still appears.

Comment: <!-- Page optimized by LiteSpeed Cache @2024-03-20 10:11:32 -->
(although it's different on different pages)

Comment: - there's nothing in there but - 
[LiteSpeed] Start Lazy Load Images
&
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.4.1

your next comment, i made a test page, and it still came with the same error, again though, it is <!-- Page optimized by LiteSpeed Cache @2024-03-20 10:23:37 -->on the lite it gives 

website is ( executivesussex.co.uk )

Comment: @Daniel it is in fact litespeed cache: inspecting your site, this is the script: https://i.imgur.com/GbBhxpx.png